# how to elegantly concatenate an Option[List] to a List?

Tags: scala

I tried to write those 3 codes without success :

```
aList.foldLeft(List()){(accu, element) => map.get(elment):::accu}
aList.foldLeft(List()){(accu, element) => if (!map.get(element).isEmpty) map.get(element):::accu}
aList.foldLeft(List()){(accu, element) => map.get(elment).exists(_:::accu)}
```

Does anyone know how to do to concatenate an Option to a list?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To concatenate an Option with a List you can just do `option.toList ++ list`

To concatenate an `Option[List[A]]` with a `List[A]` `optionOfList.toList.flatten ++ list`

The basic idea being you can always convert an option to a list of 0 or one element which makes it easy to combine them with lists in different ways.

Comment: I think `option.getOrElse(Nil) ++: list` would be a slightly better choice

Comment: Thanks both getOrElse(element,Nil) and toList.flatten work fine.
It's not relevant with the question but after reading the API I can't find : is there a difference between ++ and ++:?

Comment: ++ and ++: do the same thing i.e. `Returns a new list containing the elements from the left hand operand followed by the elements from the right hand operand` *BUT* ++: `differs from ++ in that the right operand determines the type of the resulting collection rather than the left one`. From the [scala docs for List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List)

Comment: @NikitaVolkov this is a matter of dispute. In fact 'maybe' type (`Option` in Scala) has a deep connection with 'list' type (functors forming their corresponding initial algebras are very similar, the one for lists being a more general version of the one for maybes), so converting an option to singleton/empty list is a very natural operation.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev My point was that my version should perform slightly better because it avoids creating a list from option and creating another list by flattening it, instead of which it simply either returns the option contents or a `Nil`. `++:` should definitely perform better, because it avoids traversing the righthand list.

Comment: @bruce The primary difference between `++` and `++:` is that `++` will require the traversal of both the lefthand and righthand lists while the `++:` will traverse only the left hand list, thus making it a much better performant alternative.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov This version does not compile for me `Option(3).getOrElse(Nil) ++: List(4)`  -- error: overloaded method value ++: with alternatives

Comment: @Pascalius - you'd need to wrap it in a list first, like this ```Option(List(3)).getOrElse(Nil) ++: List(4)```.

Answer (score 1):

Sprinkle some **scalaz**:

```
import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
```

And setup:

```
scala> val optList = some(List(1, 2, 3, 4)
optList: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3, 4))

scala> val list = List(5, 6, 7)
list: List[Int] = List(5, 6, 7)
```

Then I can do:

```
scala> ~optList ::: list
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Basically `~` is a unary method attached to `Option[A]` where there is a *zero* for the type `A`. The *zero* for list is of course, `Nil`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add an option to the end of the list then just use `List.++`

```
val ss = Seq(1,2)   // ss: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2)
ss ++ Option(3)     // res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers by @oxbow_lakes and @rjsvaljean are very good but they still miss one possible case that can be solved by a very idiomatic Scala:

```
scala> List(1,2,3)
res6: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> Option(List(5,6,7))
res7: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(5, 6, 7))

scala> for (l<-res7) yield l ++ res6
res8: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3))

scala> for(l<-(None:Option[List[Int]])) yield l ++ res6
res9: Option[List[Int]] = None
```

The missing case as illustrated by the above code is should `None` yield `None` instead of `Nil`?